# Sending value from ui.value (jquery UI) of a slider to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, input, contact-form-7

How can I send values of `uk-clearfix` value `js_total_value` and `uk-clearfix` value `js_total_days` to input with `id=bani_slide` and `id=timp_slide`?

Here is my shortcode from contact form 7:

```
[hidden bani id:bani_slide default:"4000"]
[hidden timp id:timp_slide default:"30"]
```

Here is link to site: http://files.mzlucas.ru/dacredit/index.html

And here my HTML code:

```
<div class="uk-clearfix labels_wrapper">
  <div class="uk-clearfix label">РАЗМЕР ЗАЙМА</div>
  <div class="uk-clearfix value js_total_value">4000</div>
  <div class="uk-clearfix drag">
    <div id="range3" class="js_range"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="uk-clearfix labels_wrapper second">
  <div class="uk-clearfix label">СРОК ЗАЙМА</div>
  <div class="uk-clearfix value js_total_days">30
  </div>
  <div class="uk-clearfix drag">
    <div id="range4" class="js_range"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: here is a man without a question who likes to post things on the internet

Comment: Now it's better ? ( Asa e mai clara intrebarea Madalin ? )

Comment: I assume the two shortcodes are hidden inputs so you want the value from the range slider into you hidden inputs yes?

Comment: what plugin do you use for the range slider?

Comment: the question is clearer now @Steve

Comment: Yes, for slider i use Nouislider, here is link https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your noUiSlider to append the value to the hidden div when the value updates

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle){
    $('#bani_slide').val(values[handle]);
});
```

for more info visit the [documentation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/)

note you have this implemented on some inputs that are on the bottom of your page you should study the scripts.js file for the implementation